# Suppressing Cherrypy's output when running unit tests using Nose

Tags: python, cherrypy, nose

I'm using cherrypy to implement a web server and I use nose to run my unit tests. However, there is a lot of debug noise that nose catches and prints to stdout, even when I use the --nologcapture, particularly cherrypy's logging messages. That makes the testing output quite difficult to read.

I've thought that:

```
def setUp(self):
   cherrypy.config.update({ "server.logToScreen" : False })
   cherrypy.config.update({'log.screen': False})
```

together with --nologcapture option would suppress those messages, but apparently it does not.

Anyone knows how to get rid of those messages and have a nice clean test output, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention which version of CherryPy you were using, but assuming 3.x based on what you are experiencing. I believe you need to add the following config option:

```
cherrypy.config.update({ "environment": "embedded" })
```

I was recently faced with the same issue when I was [testing a CherryPy app with Twill](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/11/24/testing-cherrypy-3-application-with-twill-and-nose/).

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this problem with CherryPy 3.1.2.  I switched to 3.2.2 and the problem went away without needing any code changes.